# Is it possible to check if a user belongs to an AD group without user password?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is it just me who's finding AD group is very complex? ;-(

I have a web service that only allows a certain number of role groups to have access. Say we allow people within role group 'rGroupA' to have access.

At some point, a user logs on to our web server, and we have the user name. However, we would not like to ask the user to type in the password.

Is it possible for us to know if this user belongs to 'rGroupA' somehow?

Currently, I could logon our LDAP server with my username and password and see the list of groups I am in. However, I could not search for the groups for my colleagues.

I have searched google for a while but haven't found the answer. It could be that I don't understand LDAP mechanism very well.

Many thanks!

Comment: This is called Windows Authentication. How it is implemented depends on the framework your application is built in, and what web server you are using (e.g. ASP.NET on IIS).

Comment: Thank you Gabriel! It makes sense.